# Newbie 7hours stuck at installation tutorials land

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

Guys i'm really new to this concept of getting deep with my computer but here is my problem i want to dualboot ubuntu and windows but i don't have a working usb stick. and i found this [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io) tried it. downloaded the iso from the site then i set it up extracted it and everything and the tutorial said that i needed to restart so i restarted but it's not showing what it's supposed to show, like the menu where you pick either windows or UNetbootin. i have a lenovo L530

pls help guys i'm dying and have a nice day for anyone who see this :)

Comment: You need to get a USB stick or DVD burner & drive, simply. You're likely wasting your time trying to work around this fundamental requirement.

Comment: Instead of dual booting, can install a VM like virtualbox in Windows and install the ISO to the VM.  It is safer for your data incase of a mistake.

Comment: UNetbootin has been buggy for a while. Try writing your USB with [Balena Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) and make sure you verify your downloaded .iso. Etcher is straightforward, free, and cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

UNetbootin can help you setup a bootable USB, but you you'll need a working USB stick.  Even if there are other ways to boot, like over the network, unless you're familiar with such things this is not what you want.

The best way to setup dual boot is to ensure you have Windows installed first, then install Ubuntu on top of it.  Ubuntu will let you partition the drive and keep the Windows boot, but you will need to use GRUB as your boot loader (the thing that tells the computer which partition to load when you start up).

If you already have a bootable USB but you aren't seeing to load on startup then you need to press some buttons (look it up based on your computer) to select the boot device.  It's probably F12, delete, escape or similar.  You *can* press F2 and set the boot order from the BIOS, but you'll want to change that back when you're done.

Comment: ty guys for the response but i've already tried booting from the vm thingy and i've been stuck like 3 days trying different versions disabling and enabling stuff i just can't make it work and i think my hardware is not powerful enough to emulate a os. but yeah i'll try to get a usb stick as fast as i can i'll just snatch one from my sleeping brother. have a nice day against guys.